# Angular 4.4, page will not update with changes from model

Tags: angular, typescript

I've just written a new angular component in an existing codebase, and being unfamiliar with angular 4 I can't seem to get the view to update with the changes in the model. I have viewed several similar questions, but I think my problem may be unique since their solutions did not solve my problem.

The view is simple: it has a select dropdown that affects which logs get shown on the page. When the select is changed, it calls the controller to rechoose logs.

View:

```
<nb-card size="small">
  <nb-card-header>
    <span>Filters</span>
    <br />
    <span>Log Severity: </span>
    <select id="selectVisibility" [(ngModel)]="severity" (change)="updateVisibleLogs()">
      <option value="all">All</option>
      <option value="ERR">Error</option>
      <option value="WARN">Warning</option>
      <option value="INFO">Info</option>
      <option value="DEBUG">Debug</option>
      <option value="TRACE">Trace</option>
    </select>
  </nb-card-header>
  <nb-card-body>

    <div *ngFor="let log of visibleLogs">
      {{log.msg}}
    </div>
  </nb-card-body>
</nb-card>
```

Controller:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component ({
  selector:'my-selector',
  styleUrls: ['./my-selector.component.scss'],
  templateUrl:'./my-selector.component.html'
})

export class MyComponent {

  updateVisibleLogs() {
    let visibleSeverityLevel = this.level(this.severity);
    let shouldBeVisible = true;

    this.visibleLogs = this.visibleLogs.splice(0);

    for (let i = 0; i < this.logObjects.length; i++, ) {
      shouldBeVisible = true;
      if (!isvalid(this.logObjects[i]))
        shouldBeVisible = false;

      if (shouldBeVisible)
        this.visibleLogs.push(this.logObjects[i].msg);
    }
  };

}
```

If anything pops out, please let me know :) Fairly sure this will be marked as a Duplicate question in no time at all.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up discovering that the issue was in my view.

```
<nb-card size="small">
  <nb-card-header>
    <span>Filters</span>
    <br />
    <span>Log Severity: </span>
    <select id="selectVisibility" [(ngModel)]="severity" (change)="updateVisibleLogs()">
      <option value="all">All</option>
      <option value="ERR">Error</option>
      <option value="WARN">Warning</option>
      <option value="INFO">Info</option>
      <option value="DEBUG">Debug</option>
      <option value="TRACE">Trace</option>
    </select>
  </nb-card-header>
  <nb-card-body>

    <div *ngFor="let log of visibleLogs">
      {{log.msg}} <------ this needed to be {{log}}
    </div>
  </nb-card-body>
</nb-card>
```

My scoped variable *visibleLogs* was an array of strings; I needed to diplay each string.

This problem came up because I changed *visibleLogs* from an array of Objects into an array of strings. When it was an array of Objects, it did have a msg property; not anymore though.

Comment: In the future, if you can create it in a code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/angular it is much easier for the community to help you